# Taking average of multiple Vector3's

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm working with a depth-camera that works like kinect. (it's not kinect). and with Nuitrack behind it for skeleton tracking. However, The position it returns for the player is shaky. When standing perfectly still it returns numbers that can go up or down by up to like 10.

Example: User is standing as still as he can and the data returns position 100 the first frame, and the next frame it's 102, then it's 97 then its 100 again, then it's 106 etc. It returns these positions in the update and we use it to move a image with it. (so the user controls the image) But as you might expect this image is moving very shaky because of the inconsistent data. According to Nuitrack this is right, and the user itself needs to find a solution for this.
[image]

I tried lerping from one position to another, but this makes it feel less interactive, because once i'm on the point where the lerp is actually smooth, it has a huge delay. I also tried only using the new position data if it differs lets say 4 pixels from the previous position nuitrack gave me, this works a bit better but results in jumping of the image, even if I lerp it as well. Using this function:

```
foreach (User user in frame.Users)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(_lastPos, user.Proj.ToVector3()) >4f)
            {
                Vector3 final = ((_lastPos + user.Proj.ToVector3()) /2);
                userData.Add(new UserData(user.ID, user.Real.ToVector3(), final));
                _lastPos = user.Proj.ToVector3();
            }
            else
            {
                userData.Add(new UserData(user.ID, user.Real.ToVector3(), _lastPos));
            }
```

And the lerp function:

```
float _userX = user.ProjPosition.x * (_cameraPos.x *2)- _cameraPos.x;
            Vector3 _newPos = new Vector3(_userX, _basketPos.y, _basketPos.z);
            _basketPrefab.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_basketPrefab.transform.position, _newPos, Time.deltaTime * 30f);
```

EDIT: Anyone else?

Comment: Filtering data while maintaining a good response is an art, try researchiing PID controllers and Kalman filtering

Comment: Will look into it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try keeping a list of the last n positions then calculate the average of these positions by lerping them together using `0.5f` (halfway value) as `t`. You can then increase the level of "smoothness" by Lerping the previously lerped positions again with each other, making it more smooth with every iteration. Every iteration will however make it feel a bit more sluggish, and a balance needs to be found between smooth and reactive.

(example untested).

```cs
List<Quaternion> lastPosition = new List<Quaternion>(); //Keep a list of the last positions
int smoothing = 16; //Max amount of smoothing, higher means more positions will be used for the smoothness
enum SmoothingLevels { None, Mild, Moderate, Severe, Extreme } //Level of smoothness you want to use
SmoothingLevels smoothingLevel;
Vector3 pos;

//remove the oldest entry from the list 
if(lastPosition.Count > 0)
{
    lastPosition.RemoveAt(0);
}

//Add the newest data to the list
while (lastPosition.Count < smoothing)
{
    lastPosition.Add(transform.position);
}

Vector3 vecA = lastPosition[0];
Vector3 vecB = lastPosition[1];
Vector3 vecC = lastPosition[2];
Vector3 vecD = lastPosition[3];
Vector3 vecE = lastPosition[4];
Vector3 vecF = lastPosition[5];
Vector3 vecG = lastPosition[6];
Vector3 vecH = lastPosition[7];
Vector3 vecI = lastPosition[8];
Vector3 vecJ = lastPosition[9];
Vector3 vecK = lastPosition[10];
Vector3 vecL = lastPosition[11];
Vector3 vecM = lastPosition[12];
Vector3 vecN = lastPosition[13];
Vector3 vecO = lastPosition[14];
Vector3 vecP = lastPosition[15];

//Lerp each subsequent position by t 0.5 to get the average position of the two.
//This is the base smoothing, where smoothing is low and responsiveness is high
Vector3 vecAB = Vector3.Lerp(vecA, vecB, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecCD = Vector3.Lerp(vecC, vecD, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecEF = Vector3.Lerp(vecE, vecF, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecGH = Vector3.Lerp(vecG, vecH, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecIJ = Vector3.Lerp(vecI, vecJ, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecKL = Vector3.Lerp(vecK, vecL, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecMN = Vector3.Lerp(vecM, vecN, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecOP = Vector3.Lerp(vecO, vecP, 0.5f);

//moderate smoothing, Lerp the previously lerped position again with each other to increase the smoothness
Vector3 vecABCD = Vector3.Lerp(vecAB, vecCD, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecEFGH = Vector3.Lerp(vecEF, vecGH, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecIJKL = Vector3.Lerp(vecIJ, vecKL, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecMNOP = Vector3.Lerp(vecMN, vecOP, 0.5f);

//Severe smoothing, High smoothness, lower responsiveness
Vector3 vecABCDEFGH = Vector3.Lerp(vecABCD, vecEFGH, 0.5f);
Vector3 vecIJKLMNOP = Vector3.Lerp(vecIJKL, vecMNOP, 0.5f);

//Extreme smoothing, this will take the average of all 16 positions. Very smooth, feels really sluggish
Vector3 vecABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP = Vector3.Lerp(vecABCDEFGH, vecIJKLMNOP, 0.5f);
switch (smoothingLevel)
{
    case SmoothingLevels.None:
        pos = transform.position;
        break;
    case SmoothingLevels.Mild:
        pos = vecOP;
        break;
    case SmoothingLevels.Moderate:
        pos = vecMNOP;
        break;
    case SmoothingLevels.Severe:
        pos = vecIJKLMNOP;
        break;
    case SmoothingLevels.Extreme:
        pos = vecABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP;
        break;
}

//apply pos to your target object
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the help! I tried your code, and it does work somewhat. It still shakes a little, but that can be fixed. Problem is, I would think this is a very heavy function to do each frame for 2-6 users. And not the prettiest eather. Not sure what to do now. We put this position data from the camera inside our own data class which then gets passed along to the eventual game. And your example helped, but is still not the eventual behaviour we're looking for. It feels as you said a bit sluggish

Comment: The code can indeed be made quite a bit prettier, but went for the best readable option. The performance of it really depends on the amount of passes you do with it. In my experience a maximum of 16 passes (as in the above example) gives no noticeable performance impact even when used on older android devices. Out of curiosity though, why would you need to run it 2-6 times per frame? I would assume that each user would run it on their own device, or just run it once on the object each frame and  expose the results

Comment: Yeah, I might look into how to improve it, eventhough your solution is not exactly what we're looking for, it's the closest so far. I run it so much because there can be multiple people in front of the camera. Each frame Nuitrack passes all the data for each of these users. Which can be up to 6.